# Pass html from controller to view in model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net

I'm having a problem passing html from the controller to the view. It works if I stick the html in the ViewBag and then display it with `@Html.Raw()`. The problem happens when I stick the html in a model (property type string), put the model into a view model and then use `@Html.Raw()` to display the html (the item). Instead of showing the html it gives me this:

> VB$AnonymousDelegate_0`2[System.Object,System.String]

I can't leave it in the ViewBag as the html needs to change depending on the data in the model.

As requested I've added the code (I've simplified it a bit). All works except for the `@Html.Raw(Function(modelItem) item.eventicon)` in the view.

Thanks!

---

```
Public Class activitypanel
    Public Property eventwhat As String
        Get
            Return m_eventwhat
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_eventwhat = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_eventwhat As String

    Public Property eventwhen As DateTime
        Get
            Return m_eventwhen
        End Get
        Set(value As DateTime)
            m_eventwhen = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_eventwhen As DateTime

    Public Property eventwho As String
        Get
            Return m_eventwho
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_eventwho = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_eventwho As String

    <AllowHtml>
    Public Property eventicon As String
        Get
            Return m_eventicon
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_eventicon = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_eventicon As String


    Public Property eventlink As String
        Get
            Return m_eventlink
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_eventlink = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_eventlink As String
End Class


Public Class upcomingpanel
    Public approvals As Integer
    Public tickets As Integer
    Public defects As Integer
    Public tasks As Integer
End Class
Public Class welcomeViewModel
    Public activity As IList(Of activitypanel)
    Public Property upcoming As IList(Of upcomingpanel)
End Class
```

In the Controller Action:

```
Dim actvities As New List(Of activitypanel)
Loop through data....
     Dim itemtype As Integer = drv("type")
     Dim actitem As New activitypanel

     If itemtype = 0 Then                
         actitem.eventicon = "<i class='fa fa-check fa-fw'></i>"    
     else
         ...
     end
     actvities.Add(actitem)
end loop...
Dim vm As New welcomeViewModel()
vm.upcoming = upcoming
vm.activity = actvities
Return View(vm)
```

In the view:

```
<table class="table table-hover ">

    <tbody>
        @For Each item In Model.activity
            @<tr>
                <td style=" text-wrap:none;width:20%;">

                    @Html.Raw(Function(modelItem) item.eventicon)

                    @Html.DisplayFor(Function(modelItem) item.eventwho)

                    @Html.DisplayFor(Function(modelItem) item.eventwhat)
                </td>
            </tr>
            @<tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(Function(modelItem) item.eventwhen)
                </td>
            </tr>
        Next
    </tbody>
```

Comment: Instead of trying to describe the code which demonstrates the problem, can you actually *show* it?

Comment: `@Html.Raw()` accepts a string as its parameter. Try `@Html.Raw(item.eventicon)`

Comment: Tried that but same result. It just displays <i class='fa fa-check fa-fw'></i>  instead of the actual icon. thanks

Comment: Can you post `fa fa-check fa-fw'` those classes styles? And also check if `image` icon source is not breaking in F12 developer tools.

Comment: it's just a font-awesome icon. If I take the string above (<i class='fa fa-check fa-fw'></i>) and use @html.raw("<i class='fa fa-check fa-fw'></i>") it works fine so I know the icon is there and the markup is fine. It's just when I pass this from the controller in a model that it breaks.

Comment: Can you try just `@item.eventicon` (without `Html.Raw()`) to see what happens?

Comment: I tried just @item.eventicon but no success.Got &lt;i class=&#39;fa fa-check fa-fw&#39;&gt;&lt;/i&gt; displayed. Thanks #doingmyheadin

Answer (score 0):

OK. I have a solution (for anyone else that runs into this problem).

1. In the model definition add the following to the property that holds the html:

   ```
    <AllowHtml> <DataType(DataType.Html)>
      Public Property eventicon As String
           Get
               Return m_eventicon
           End Get
           Set(value As String)
               m_eventicon = value
           End Set
       End Property
   ```
2. In the view use `@html.displayfor`

   ```
       @Html.DisplayFor(Function(modelItem) item.eventicon)
   ```

that's it. thanks for the feedback and suggestions.